# Textarea data in form are not saved in mongoose however i can log it in server side code as req.body.bio

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

`<form>
<input1>
...
...
<textarea name="yourbio" rows="3" value="<%= user.bio %>"></textarea>
<submit....>
<form>`

I am using $set: {req.body} to update the user. I can update all the fields but i cant update the bio field. I can log the value using console.log(req.body.bio).
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code for textarea

```
 <textarea name="yourbio" rows="3" > <%= user.bio %> </textarea>
```